# JsonConvert not working on list of structures inside class

Tags: json, deserialization, restsharp, nested-object

Hello i want to deserialize a class which contains a `string`, a `bool` and a `List<[mystructtype>`;
When using `JsonConvert.Deserialize<[myclass]>` it deserializes the `string` and the `bool` correctly but not the `List<[Struct]>`.I have also changed the `List<struct>` with an array of `structs`.
Both the `class` container and the `struct` are marked with `Serializeable` and i do not understand where the problem is.
Can anyone help me?

**Struct**
`[Serializable]
    public struct Status
    {
        //identifiers
        public long playerId { get; set; }
        public long groupId { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
    }`

**Class Container**

```
[Serializable]
    class GatewayDeviceResponse
    {
        public bool status { get; set; }  //gets deserialized good
        public string message { get; set; } //gets deserialized good

        public Status[] data { get; set; }   // all members  are defaults
    }
```

**Deserialization**

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RawBytes);

                GatewayDeviceResponse resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GatewayDeviceResponse>(result);
                return resp.data.ToList();
```

**P.S** The string is a response from a `webserver`,and i am using `RestSharp` for creating the server request and getting the response.The thing is the `response` string is good.The `class` is `deserialized` good excluding the `collection`.

What could the problem be?

**P.S**
The string response from the server i get is :

```
   "{  
   \"status\":true,
   \"message\":\"ok\",
   \"data\":[  
      {  
         \"status\":{  
            \"playerId\":59,
            \"groupId\":26,
            \"type\":2,
            \"deviceId\":\"abababa",
            \"groupName\":\"srl\",
            \"playerName\":\"Adrian\"
         }
      },
      {  
         \"status\":{  
            \"playerId\":25,
            \"groupId\":26,
            \"type\":1,
            \"deviceId\":\"lalal\",
            \"groupName\":\"srl\",
            \"playerName\":\"Alex\"
         }
      }
   ]
}"
```

The `Status[]` array elements  are not supposed to be fully filled by the server response , just the 3 fields i have posted in the `POCO`/

Comment: Can you share the server response string which you try to deserialize?

Comment: I have added the response i get .As i said the first 2 fields are serialized ok .But the `Array` is not.Could it be that i am using a list of `struct` ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a unit test as below and it passes and correctly deserialized with restsharp. Can you replace your response string and classes to check unit test still pass?

May be your class representation is not fit for your response. Take a little help from http://json2csharp.com/ and check your classes represents your json correctly.

```
[Test]
public void Can_Deserialize_Struct()
{
    var data = "{ \"myList\":[{\"name\": \"test1234\"}] }";

    JsonDeserializer json = new JsonDeserializer();
    var output = json.Deserialize<MyTest>(new RestResponse { Content = data });

    Assert.NotNull(output);
}

class MyTest
{
    public List<MyStruct> MyList { get; set; }
}

struct MyStruct
{
    public String name { get; set; }
}
```

According to your response string, your c# classes should represent your json as below :

```
public class Status
{
    public int playerId { get; set; }
    public int groupId { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public string deviceId { get; set; }
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public string playerName { get; set; }
}

public class StatusData
{
    public Status status { get; set; }
}

public class GatewayDeviceResponse
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<StatusData> data { get; set; }
}
```

It does not related with type struct or class. You need to add another class in front of your status representation class. Because it starts as a json object in your response string.

Comment: I have added the response i get.

Comment: I've edited my answer according to your response, you should change your classes as above. It will serialize successfully.